# C# SEHException when trying to access personal folder

Tags: c#, exception

Using C#, I'm getting a SEHEXception whenever I try to get the path to my personal folder via

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
```

The detailed exception is:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException was unhandled
  Message=External component has thrown an exception.
  Source=mscorlib
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
    at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner, Int32 nFolder, 
                               IntPtr hToken, Int32 dwFlags, StringBuilder lpszPath)
    at System.Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder folder, 
                                                      SpecialFolderOption option)
    at System.Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder folder)
    [...]
```

There's no InnerException.

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong? The problem does not occur when I try to get the system path, for example. I'm using Windows XP SP3 and Visual Studio 2010. 
Also, I had a friend with vista and VS2005 try to do this on his machine and he doesn't get this Exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch, but by any chance are you running this code from an MTA thread?

I know that *some* Windows Shell API calls will fail if they are not running in STA. Truth be told, I have only ever encountered this problem when I was doing PInvoke stuff, but this call to the native `SHGetFolderPath` function in your stack trace tells me it just might be it.

So... to test my theory, can you try calling `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)` from `Main` in a simple console application and see if this call succeeds?

If it succeeds in a simple dummy application, then maybe MTA is the cause of failure in your app.

If it fails in a simple dummy application, your machine is probably messed up, or maybe just the user's profile. I would try creating a new user on the machine, logon to his account and try from there.

**Edit:** 
Trying some more directions:

- Look directly at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` in Regedit and check if everything looks normal.
- Check Event Viewer if other things are corrupted on the machine.
- Restart the machine...? :)
- Reinstall .NET Framework

Comment: The problem was already from a simple dummy application. Trying to do this with a newly created user also yields the same error.